# How to write a first solidity contract in remix - ide online?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have written a small contract which is just to set and get a name. I choose JavaScript VM, when I deployed it and set my name as "vijay" and when I selected getname. I didn't got output. It shows error as attached in below image.

Please Give me a solution. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please paste code instead of uploading image. So others can copy paste and replicate your issue.

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract sample{
    string private name;
    function setName(string newName){
        name=newName;
    }
    
    function getName()returns (string){
        return(name);
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can not get return values from a non-constant function.

**Constant functions**: The functions which do not change state on blockchain are marked constant (now view) or pure. See [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#view-functions)

**Non Constant functions**: The functions that change state on blockchain, like `setName`. These functions need gas to be executed. These functions only return transaction hash if not called from another contract. (There are many ifs and buts, I am skipping for simplicity). The only way to get return value is use [events](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#events)

You can use `view` in `getName` function to gethe t desired result.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0; 
contract sample{ 
  string private name; 

  function setName(string newName){
     name=newName; 
  } 

  function getName() public view returns (string){ 
    return name; 
  } 
}
```

**Note:** You are using quite old solidity version. The latest version is **0.4.24**.

Comment: It showed error as below: declaration error, undeclared variable

Comment: updated the code. Please check

Comment: yeah, its working. Ok, i have doubt - why didn't the output come when we keep only return but it came when we used "view return"

Comment: As per i followed a video, they got output without adding "view returns", what could be the problem?

Comment: I already explained this in answer. If you use `view` you cannot update state. Since this `getName` did not update any state, you can mark this as view and get return values

Comment: They must be using `constant` keyword which is now `view`. Without this you can not get values , you will always get a transaction hash. You can decode the output of transaction to get the name. But this is the simpleste and ideal way, I recommend to stick to this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hU0jPtLto&list=PL16WqdAj66SCOdL6XIFbke-XQg2GW_Avg this is link which i followed they used only "returns " but not "view returns". why? and how to execute non constant functions with gas in remix -ide online

Comment: I shall have a look. But you can go ahead with this. This is the way of getting values. Not all sources are reliable. Do your research before implementing.

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract sample {
    string private name;

        function setName(string newName) {
            name = newName;
        }
        function getName() public view returns (string) {
            return (name);
        }
    }
```

You need to declare your getName function as public view for it to return your name variable (you're trying to READ a value, however you've implemented it as WRITE). Also, consider using the latest stable compiler version, specify proper function visibility, and follow the recommended Solidity coding style (stick to best practices).

Answer (score -1):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: nolicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 
contract sample{ 
  string public name; 

  function setName(string memory _newName) public returns(bool){
     name =_newName; 
     return true; 
  } 

  function getName() public view returns (string memory){ 
    return name; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: If you want to answer a 4 years old question you have to provide more substance. There are already two other answers with similar code that have at least an explanation of the possible issue.

Comment: First of all, please check my code according to latest version of solidity complier. So please more enhance to self skills. Thank you.

Comment: The contract is fine, but it is just code. You should add a paragraph or two explaining your answer and how does it solves the question asked. Also you may consider answering newer question, or questions without answers.